# Nonlinear Schrodinger equation involving derivative of Abs causes ndnum warning

Tags: differential-equations

So, I'm using `NDSolve` to approximate the solution to a Schrödinger like equation

$i\psi_{t} + \psi_{xx} + \frac{1}{2}|\psi|^{2} \psi + \lambda \left( \left[|\psi|^{2} \psi\right]_{xx} + |\psi|^{4} + \psi \right) =0$

where $\psi: \mathbb{R}^{1+1} \to \mathbb{C}$. To do this I've modified the code from [http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Built-inFunctions/NumericalComputation/EquationSolving/FurtherExamples/NDSolve.html)(search for soliton to find the code) to include the $\lambda$ terms. I've tested the code for $\lambda =0$ and things are working just fine.

The problem I'm having is that when I include the second derivative term for $\lambda \neq 0$, Mathematica encounters a non-numerical derivative at $t=0$. I've looked at the second derivative of the initial condition

```
F[s_] = Soliton[1, π/12, m, 0][s, 0.]
```

and found that Mathematica yields

```
N[F[0]] = 2. ((0. + 
 0. I) + (0.999902 - 4.31242*10^-21 I) ((0. + 0.261799 I) - 
  0.261799 Derivative[1][Im][0.]))
```

and so I think that the problem is that it is keeping around the derivative of the imaginary part of a manifestly real quantity.

I'd like to get it to not work so hard at something so simple and would like to pass it something like $s \in \mathbb{R}$, but I can't figure out a way to do so. Is there a way to tell Mathematica to treat $s$ a little simpler?

Edit: Relevant codes.

```
Soliton[a_, b_, m_, s0_][s_, t_] := Module[{omega, ek, xx = s - s0}, 
omega = (2 m - 1) a^2 - b^2; Sqrt[m] a JacobiCN[a (xx - 2 b t), m] Exp[I (b xx + omega t)]];

per[m_] := 4 EllipticK[m];

m = mm /. FindRoot[per[mm] == 24, {mm, 0.5}];

ψ = u /. 
First@ NDSolve[{I D[u[s, t], t] + D[u[s, t], {s, 2}] + 
    1/2 Abs[u[s, t]]^2  u[s, t] + 
    (1/16) (D[Abs[u[s, t]]^2 u[s, t], {s, 2}] + 
       Abs[u[s, t]]^4 u[s, t]) == 0, 
  u[s, 0.] == 2 Soliton[1, π/12, m, 0][s, 0], 
  u[-24, t] == u[24, t]}, u, {t, 0., 20.}, {s, -24., 24.}, 
 MaxSteps -> Infinity, MaxStepSize -> 0.2, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "MinPoints" -> 100, "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}, 
   Method -> {"Adams", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 4}}];
```

> NDSolve::ndnum

Comment: I suspect `Im'[..]` comes from how you coded in `Soliton` and has little to do with `s`.  You'd need to post the code for someone else to be able to check it out.

Comment: That's interesting. I've posted the codes and will next look into the issues associated with the module. Thanks!

Comment: Is `m` supposed to have a value?  For `N[F[0]]` I get `(1. + 0. I) Sqrt[m] JacobiCN[0., m]` with what it posted.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Now I get [`0.999951 - 4.31264*10^-21 I`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rrTnA.png) for `N[F[0]]` -- no `Im'[]`.  Have you tried starting from a fresh kernel?

Comment: Yeah. I've included a code block that can be run straight-up. If you set the (1/16) term to 0 then you get a tidy traveling wave solution to the evolution. Keeping the 1/16 term throws the error, which goes away when you omit the second derivative term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of evil is `Abs'[…]`, which is generated by `D[Abs[u[s, t]]^2 u[s, t], {s, 2}]` in the equation. (`D` cannot handle `Abs[…]` properly. ) To resolve the problem we need to express $|\psi|^{2}$ in a differentiable way. Notice that

$$\left| \psi \right| ^2=\psi  \psi ^*$$
$$\frac{\partial \psi ^*}{\partial s}=\left(\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial s}\right)^*$$

We reform the equation to

```
eq = With[{abs = Abs[u[s, t]], abssquare = u[s, t] uconj[s, t]}, 
      {I D[u[s, t], t] + D[u[s, t], {s, 2}] + 
         1/2 abs^2 u[s, t] + (1/16) (D[abssquare u[s, t], {s, 2}] + abs^4 u[s, t]) == 0, 
       u[s, 0.] == 2 Soliton[1, π/12, m, 0][s, 0], 
       u[-24, t] == u[24, t]}] /. 
     (uconj | Derivative[d__][uconj])[s, t] :> Conjugate[Derivative[d][u][s, t]];
```

You may find part of the definition of `eq` confusing. To understand it, just notice the following truth:

1. `a /. a | b[m_] :> {m}` outputs `{}`.
2. `Derivative[][u]` outputs `u`.

Now `NDSolve` can handle the equation with a manual adjustion for `Method` option:

```
mol[n_Integer, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

sol = u /. First@
     NDSolve[eq, u, {t, 0., 20}, {s, -24., 24.}, Method -> mol[51]]; // AbsoluteTiming
DensityPlot[Abs@sol[s, t], {s, -24, 24}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At least in *v9*, the manual adjustion for `Method` is necessary, or `NDSolve` will spit out `ndnum` warning and fails again. I think it's another bug of `NDSolve`.