# Derivative of Abs[]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I ran into difficulties caused by the derivative of the absolute function.
Surprisingly, the origin seems to be handled reasonably: problems originate for the  argument $\neq 0$.

I have a function such that $h(x) = h(-x)$. 
For the purposes of a minimal example, the following will do

```
  h[x_] := Abs[x]^3
  hder[x_] := D[h[z], z] /. z -> x
  hder[2]
```

outputs

```
   (* 12 Abs'[2] *)
```

What is the workaround? I found a similar post, [Nonlinear Schrodinger equation involving derivative of Abs causes ndnum warning](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146716/nonlinear-schrodinger-equation-involving-derivative-of-abs-causes-ndnum-warning) , but I am not so sure the related solution is generally applicable.

A solution I found for now, is to define

```
   h1[x_] := (Sqrt[x^2])^3
```

squaring and taking the root, but I am sure there is something far more elegant.

Comment: use `RealAbs` instead of `Abs`?

Comment: Is `x` always `Real`? If so, as mentioned by @kglr , `RealAbs` is the way to go.

Comment: @xzczd, thanks it does. Thanks to all the others too, much appreciated, you are the only force preventing me from going back to Fortran, I am grateful.